# Get distinct months from database using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I have a `java.util.Date` field in an `@Entity` and would like to get the distinct months from that column.

Suppose I only had three rows, with 14/07/2010, 24/11/1975 and 03/11/1975 (European date format - day/month/year), I would like to get the following back from Hibernate to go into a dropdown for filtering the data:

```
07/2010
11/1975
```

(or corresponding Date objects with the other fields set to zero - to be honest precisely how the data comes back isn't too important as I can work around that).

I'm guessing a database-agnostic approach in HQL isn't possible - any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about :

```
select distinct month(c.birthday), year(d.birthday) from Cat c
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't expecting it to be so simple!

Comment: this doesn't work when using postgre. 

"function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types."